# Android - Oauth2 - Server-side access for your app

Tags: android, google-oauth

I've been having problems implementing Google Play Services login on my android app and passing the authorisation code to my backend server, so the server will exchange the code for access token and refresh token.

First let me write a few lines what has already been tried/read:

- on code.google.com/apis/console I've created a new project, with two clients (WEB client and Android installed client)
- read articles on https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#cross-platform_single_sign_on and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Next I wrote simple android app (based on Google Play Services sample auth app) and a simple python code using gdata (using web service client_id and secret).

On android app I first used four scopes delimited with space and got a token. If I use this token in my python code I always get {'error_message': 'unauthorized_client'}.

Then I tried to change the scope to this values and always got invalid scope error.

- oauth2:server:client_id:server-client-id:api_scope:scope1 scope2
- audience:server:client_id:server-client-id:api_scope:scope1 scope2
- oauth2:audience:server:client_id:server-client-id:api_scope:scope1 scope2

For server-client-id I used the client_id of web server client, android client, other client

Please can anyone help me with this problem.

Thanx

Here is the code for python backend

```
import gdata
import gdata.gauth


CLIENT_ID = 'client_id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'secret_id'
SCOPES = ["https://www.google.com/m8/feeds", "https://mail.google.com", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]
USER_AGENT = 'my-app'

token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, scope=' '.join(SCOPES), user_agent=USER_AGENT)

print "token ", token
print token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_url='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

try:
  print token.get_access_token("token")
except Exception, e:
  print e
  print e.__dict__
```

Comment: Can please someone help me with this problem I am having.

Comment: Could you list the details of the call you're making on the Android side?  It's a little confusing because you say you're getting a "token" and an "authorization code" which are two very different things.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. If I make a call to getAuthToken with string of four space delimited scopes, I get a token (suppose it is a access token), and then I can use this token to get data (contacts, user info) from google. I can not use this token to get the refresh token and access token.
But if I want to get the authorisation code using Google Play Service,  using the scope combinations mentioned above (containing client-id of the web server) I always get invalid scope response from the google servers.

Hope I was clear enough about what issue I am having.

Best Jure

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving an authorization code, not an access token. These are two different things.

Authorization codes [can be used in your server side to get an access token](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#server-side_access_for_your_app). They are not access tokens and cannot be used as such.

Comment: Hey @nacho, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown.  Any idea why? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Comment: Typically you should review your scopes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171956/unable-to-get-authorization-code-with-google-sign-in-for-android-invalid-scope

Comment: Is there something wrong with these scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Comment: yeah thats not helpful at all is it! 'Unknown'. I was getting this as I was using my devices clientId instead of the servers clientId in the google cloud console as part of the scope string