# Unable to get Authorization Code with Google+ Sign-in for Android: INVALID_SCOPE

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-services

I am trying to retrieve an authorization code to use in my server side following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#server-side_access_for_your_app). The client ID of the server shares the same project of my Android Client ID.

I can retrieve the access token, but not the authorization code:

```
String mScopes = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
//String mScopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:314345278679.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
Bundle mAppActivities = new Bundle();
mAppActivities.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES, "");
String authorizationToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(LoginActivity.this, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), mScopes, mAppActivities);
```

Uncommenting to use the alternative scope (to retrieve an authorization code instead of a token) produces the following error:

```
I/GLSUser (15293): GLS error: INVALID_SCOPE my_email_address@company.com oauth2:server:client_id:314345278679.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login from your scopes.  I tried your code and get INVALID_SCOPE without plus.login, but it works fine with.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried this already, but probably used the wrong scope.

Comment: Hey @Lee, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Comment: hm, i also get an unknow error, can't seem to find a way for it to work