# Android Google+ unable to get authorization code

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-calendar-api

I want to enable server-side Calendar API access for my android app.

I have followed the steps given [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app) .

I am getting a null value for the authorization code.

I think I am giving wrong values for 'scope' field and the 'server_client_id' field.

Please give me an example showing correct fields values for 'scope' and 'server_client_id' in the getToken() method.

Thanks for any help.

PS- I have used google+ sign in for android given [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) for connecting to a google account.

EDIT- Here is my code. I have given the OAuth 2.0 scope for the Google Calendar API in the scope field.

I have taken Client ID for Android application from Developers Console and put in 'serverClientID' field. This is probably where I am wrong. I don't know how to get Server's Client ID which is required by the

```
public class AsyncGetAuthToken extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
        appActivities.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES,
                "MainActivity");
        String scopeString = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";
        String serverClientID = CLIENT_ID;
        String scopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + serverClientID + ":api_scope:" + scopeString;
        String code = null;
        try {
            code = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                    MainActivity.this,                                 // Context context
                    Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),  // String accountName
                    scopes,                                            // String scope
                    appActivities                                      // Bundle bundle
            );                

        } catch (IOException transientEx) {
            // network or server error, the call is expected to succeed if you try again later.
            // Don't attempt to call again immediately - the request is likely to
            // fail, you'll hit quotas or back-off.
            return null;
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            // Requesting an authorization code will always throw
            // UserRecoverableAuthException on the first call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken
            // because the user must consent to offline access to their data.  After
            // consent is granted control is returned to your activity in onActivityResult
            // and the second call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken will succeed.
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE);
            return null;
        } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
            // Failure. The call is not expected to ever succeed so it should not be
            // retried.
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in my onActivityResult, I look for the Auth Code

```
if (requestCode == AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (responseCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            String oneTimeToken = extra.getString("authtoken");
            Log.d("LOG", "one time token" + oneTimeToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show your request and response?

Comment: @Owen Cao I have added my code. Please have a look. Also my app does not have a web component. So What do i put in the 'server's OAuth 2.0 client ID' field in the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method.

Comment: Did you add  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login  scope?? check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171956/unable-to-get-authorization-code-with-google-sign-in-for-android-invalid-scope

Comment: @SGC Thanks for the response. I have added the plus.login scope. Still it gives a null value in auth code. Could you please suggest something else.

Comment: I got a 'client ID for my android application' after I registered it at Google developers. Do we have to put the same id in 'server client ID' field (in getToken method) or we need to put something else.?